# ffmpeg + libx264: use preset

Tags: ffmpeg, x264

I'm trying to encode raw movie using **ffmpeg** with **libx264**.
I use the following command:
`ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -s '3840x2160' -r 23.98 -i <my source> -pass 1 -x264-params 'bitrate=13500:fps=23.98:keyint=48:preset=veryfast:pass=1:threads=0' -vcodec libx264 -f mp4 -threads 0 <my destimation>`

The problem is that I get the following error from **ffmpeg**:
*Error parsing option 'preset = veryfast'*

Does anybody know why I can't pass preset through **-x264-params**? I have already found that I can pass it through direct **-preset:v** option, but I'm still confused about **-x264-params** - is something broken in ffmpeg?

Comment: Unrelated, but  `-video_size` and `-framerate` should be used instead of `-s` and `-r` with the [rawvideo demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo) (but I don't know if that actually makes a difference). Are you sure you want to use 23.98 instead of `24000/1001` or the alias `ntsc-film`? Why do you want to use `-x264-params`? Lastly, please show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: Thanks for additional information.  
About `-s` and `-r` - actually no difference, as I see.  
About `ntsc-film` - thanks, simply didn't know about it.  
And about `-x264-params` - it's mainly theoretical question now, I found a workaround with *-preset:v veryfast*, and now I'm simply interested why **preset** doesn't work in x264 params string.  
Complete console output is rather long, and everything else seems OK (and the command produces correct file using default preset, as I can see - it simply ignores *preset=veryfast*).